# Excel File "Not Responding" issue

Tags: excel, xml, excel-formula

i have a excel file, not significantly big in size (5 MB) however, whenever i open it for first 5-10 sec it works seamlessly and then it keeps **Not Responding* in a cyclic pattern.

i started searching for possible solutions and have done the following.

1- inspect elements = deleted any hidden data etc.
2- deactivated any add-ins or macros (my sheet didnt had any macro)
3- checked for names (deleted irrelevant names)
4- edited the links to external sources and have broken the link
5- converted the file to zip > extracted data to checked if there were duplicated images found none.
6- Excel xl/CalcChain.xml seems to be big (6MB) but i don't know how i can debug that.

Can someone please check the sheet and see what i should do to fix the issue.

[Source File] - i am unable to upload on any data repository websites due to company policy and blocks. can share file by email.

Comment: I don't think your company allows sending it to a random person either

Comment: The issue is resolved. little more digging and i was able to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. there were many linked images in my file and every time i was copying the file, the linked images were being copied within that sheet as superimposed multiple images. if you have similar situation, Following steps might also resolve the issue for you.

1. change the excel file extension to .zip
2. Extract all .zip file
3. go to xl/drawings
4. look for vmlDrawing with biggest size
5. Open it in notepad
6. Here you will find if one picture is being
   pasted more than one time. you will be able to identify sheet name
   and cell reference. search for similar cell range and see if there
   are any duplications.

[image: vmlDrawing]

7. you can delete it in the code or go to your excel file and delete images on specific page.
8. incase you have deleted in notepad, after deletion, re-zip the complete folder and change the file extension back to .xlsx